# How to use another attribute of a Rails resource in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, activerecord

I am trying to follow http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url to achieve URLs that look like:

`/dog/<custom field of dog>`

instead of

`/dog/1`

Where "1" is the internal primary key of the Dogs table. The custom field I want happens to be another integer in the Dogs field.

My code:

dogs_controller.rb:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:index]    
def show
       Rails.logger.info("Hello")
       @dog = Dog.find_by_custom_field(params[:id])
    end
```

dog.rb:

```
def to_param
    custom_field
end
```

In particular, when I try to load `/dogs/<custom_field>`, it still insists on using that integer as the primary key lookup, instead of looking up on the custom field. So I get a `Couldn't find Dog with id=<custom_field>`. error

Interestingly, the logger line also never gets printed when I try to do this. However, when I remove the `load_and_authorize_resource` (CanCan) line, then it works. What is going on here?

Comment: Don't you just need to rewrite the `routes` setting? Like `/dog/:custom_field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using a different attribute other than id pass :find_by option

```
 load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:index]  , :find_by => :custom # will use find_by_custom!(params[:id])
```

for more info read cancan manual for controller methods
http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/master/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods